# Is clang++ ignoring extern "C" for some deprecation warnings?

Tags: c++, multilingual, clang++, extern-c

If I use clang 3.8.1 to compile:

```
extern "C" {
int foo(int x) { register int y = x; return y; }
}

int main() { return foo(123); }
```

I get the warning:

```
a.cpp:3:18: warning: 'register' storage class specifier is deprecated and incompatible with C++1z [-Wdeprecated-register]
int foo(int x) { register int y = x; return y; }
                 ^~~~~~~~~
```

... which I really shouldn't be getting this, since the inner function is C code. If I use GCC 6.3.1, even with `-Wall`, I don't get this warning.

Is this a clang bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That's not related to C!

Comment: The code ist still C++ code! `extern "C"` just specifies the ABI and nameing conventions. (did you even read the warning?)

Comment: `extern "C"` only has effect on linkage of external names - it doesn't' change the compiler to 'C-mode'.

Comment: either fix it, or compile this part in C - whichever makes sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`extern "C"` does not mean "compile this code as C". It means "make this function (or functions) callable from C code", which typically means changing name mangling and, sometimes, calling convention.

Comment: Another way to  look at it: it means "the **name** of this function is in C," rather than the **body**.

Comment: @JohnZwinck - it can involve more than the name.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Not exactly. It also implys C calling conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the error has nothing to do with the `extern "C"`?  It looks like it says, not, "register is incompatible with C" but rather "register is incompatible with C++1z".  (I assume C++1x means C++11/14/17.)